# Mpv not running youtube urls because youtube-dl is out of date

Tags: linux-mint, youtube-dl, mpv, youtube

I'm using Linux Mint 21.1 and I recently installed mpv. When I run `mpv` followed by a youtube url I get the following lines:

```
[ytdl_hook] ERROR: Unable to extract updater id: please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug. Make sure you are using the latest version...
[ytdl_hook] youtube-dl failed: unexpected error occurred
[ytdl_hook] It appears that your youtube-dl version is severely out of date
Failed to recognize title format
```

It seems that the problem is that my youtube-dl is out of date, but when I command `youtube-dl --update` I get that `youtube-dl is up-to-date (2021.12.17)`. What am I failing to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project has not been maintained recently and it's indeed out of date. Please upgrade to/replace it with yt-dlp.

Comment: Thank you. How do I setup mpv with yt-dlp?

Comment: `sudo apt remove youtube-dl`; https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+mint+install+yt-dlp

Comment: Recent versions of `mpv` will use `yt-dlp` automatically if that's the only one of them installed :-)

Comment: After a few days of looking into it it seems that installing it through the terminal actually downloads an outdated version. Had to build it and change the conf file to make it so it works with `yt-dlp`. Thanks for the help :)